# EMERGENCY! How do I recover lost lotus notes design elements

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

HELP.  I accidentally deleted a bunch of xpages and custom control out of my database and have no backup.  is there any way of recovering those elements?

Answer (score 6):

Presumably you don't have source control enabled. If not, there's one way, best done on the same PC where each design element was last edited.

1. Create a brand new XPage with the same name.
2. Go to the source pane
3. Right-click and choose Compare With... > Local History

If it was last saved recently on that PC, you'll see the previous version.

For the future, I strongly recommend using Source Control and outputting to the On Disk Project and committing frequently to a source control repository. I did a session and a Notes In 9 a few years ago on source control and the Show and Tell slides on my blog (accessible from your favourite search engine) show how to install Redmine (courtesy of Declan Lynch) or Stash (courtesy of me). Alternatively BitBucket allow private repositories accessible for up to five users. This is one of those cautionary tales of why source control is relevant even if you're not working in a team. There are DXL rouond-tripping issues with some edge case traditional design elements, which is another reason I tend to keep my XPages UI in a separate database from my design (which has the views, forms, agents etc).

Comment: Good idea Paul!

Answer (score 0):

There is no undelete for design elements (or documents). Sure you don't have a backup somewhere?

This is where source control is handy...

Sorry...

Comment: I tried what Paul said with a Custom Control but it didn't find any local history.  I had some three week old backup so I recovered some major work but the last three weeks are gone.  Much of that time was spent on CSS and trying to get certain things to work so I probably lost a week of solid work which we all know, takes half the time the second time.  So I'm not as bad off as I thought.  I have to learn version control though.  Never used it. Thank you for all your comments